# Unity3d: Texture viewable from inside object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I am trying to make a globe around the camera so that everywhere the camera views it is surrounded by the texture placed on the globe.

I have been able to achieve the exact effect i am after by setting the shader of the sphere to Particles/Alpha Blended, and putting the camera inside the sphere. This way I have the camera inside a sphere object and all around it is the texture.

My problem though is this. I want to use a chroma key shader (to remove all occurances of a color) on the globe object. This means the shader is not set to Particles/Alpha Blended. And from inside the object the walls of the sphere are not textured.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to how i could achieve the effect i am after. I have a few ideas, however im not sure how to go about it. Im thinking i could:

1) Edit the chroma key shader to work in the same way as a Particles/Alpha Blended shader would (I have no experience in shader coding, or anything of the sort) 2) Use a hollow sphere, rather than the solid one unity creates (Im not sure where i would get that) 3) Use a different object all together that just renders a texture in a sphere shape, without it being a fully solid object (Im not sure if such a thing exists)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have searched the forums and cannot find what i am looking for.

Comment: Have you considered using a skybox?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, but im not sure it will do exactly what i need. i eventually want to manipulate the globe, and use multiple globes to create some interesting effects. So i dont think a skybox will be able to be used like this. good idea though, and thanks for the reply.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with shaders, sorry, but it sounds like the particular shader you're currently using allows you to view your texture from inside even though the object is actually textured on the outside. It sounds like you could use your chroma keyer given the texture displayed inside the object in the first place. This should be fairly simple and I dug up this link, I don't know if it will be of use to you; http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/176487/materialtexture-on-the-inside-of-a-sphere.html

Comment: Yes this link helped perfectly. I modified the shader and added 'Cull Off' so that it doesn't cull the inside of the sphere when it renders. Thank you very much! :)